# Airflow ExternalTaskSensor Stuck and Error

Tags: airflow

I have define the external_sensor like that:

```
external_sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(task_id='ext_sensor_task',
                execution_delta=timedelta(minutes=0),
                external_dag_id='book_data',
                external_task_id='Dataframe_Windows_test',
                dag = dag)
```

The another task is defined like this:

```
dl_processing_windows = DL_Processing(task_id='dl_processing_windows',
                df_dataset_location=dl_config.WINDOWS_DATASET,
....
```

While in the airflow UI:
I got the error:
Argument ['task_id'] is required

I have two problems:
1. Why does such error exist?
2. Why does it not work?

The attachment:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'Newt',
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=30),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    }

dag = DAG(
    dag_id,
    start_date = datetime(2019, 11, 20),
    description= 'xxxx',
    default_args = default_args,
    schedule_interval = timedelta(hours=1),
    )
```

The parameters for dag are the same for both dags!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.
Normally, the start_date is different from the scheduler_interval. I set the start_date for both dags into the same time with the current date.

After the first dependent bag finished, the new dag began to work!

Comment: And the error about task_id is fixed after I restarted the whole server. The commands include: ``` airflow initdb --> airflow webserver;    airflow scheduler(the crucial command)```